# Routing to the Home Controller Index Action in MVC with Blazor Server Also Configured

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project with a Blazor Server project, how to make the default route go to the MVC home controller index action, and NOT Blazor `Index.razor`?

This is how I am setting the endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code:

```cs
            services.AddRazorPages();
```

To:

```cs
            services.AddRazorPages(o => o.RootDirectory="/Identity/Account/" );
```

Now I go straight to the login page and after that straight to the home controller index action.